# My plots only show in a separate window. How can I undo this?

Tags: r, graphics, rstudio, rna-seq, gplots

I am using RStudio and doing scRNA sequencing analysis. I am trying to plot my clusters and they keep pooping up in a new window called R Graphics: Device 2 (ACTIVE).

This is my code:

`DimPlot(pbmc.seurat.filtered, reduction = 'umap')`

I already tried:
`dev.off()`
and go to Tools->Global options->R Mark down -> select "window" from that list in the "show output preview in:"

Also tried `options(device = "RStudioGD")` and still pops up a new window.

My R is updated to 4.3.0 ans RStudio is 3.51 (they say it's the latest).

Is there **any way** I can put my graphics back into the plots in Rstudio instead of a new window??

Thank you so much!!

Comment: When you went to In "Show output preview in" and selected "Viewer Pane" did you also uncheck the box "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents"?

Comment: yes and still does not work :'(

Comment: Are you using Mac OS? What is the result if you run `options("device")`?

Comment: I am using Windowns 10. It gives back this ```options("device")
function (width, height, pointsize, record, rescale, xpinch, 
    ypinch, bg, canvas, gamma, xpos, ypos, buffered, title, restoreConsole, 
    clickToConfirm, fillOddEven, family = "", antialias) 
{
    check <- Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_", "")
    msg <- "screen devices should not be used in examples etc"
    if (identical(check, "stop")) 
        stop(msg, domain = NA)```
(...) It's a lot of code, I cant fit it here

Comment: Okay, now try 1) uninstall RStudio, 2) update R to the most recent version `R 4.3.2`, 3) reinstall the most recent version of RStudio `RStudio 2023.12.1+402`

Comment: THIS ACTUALLY WORKED!! Thank you so so so so much!! I've been trying for almost 2 weeks now :') and all tha packages and everything is fine :') thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using dev.off() until you see the following message:

```
null device 
          1
```

After that type `dev.new()` and try plotting something.

Comment: it keeps opening in a new window :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

try 1) uninstall RStudio, 2) update R to the most recent version R 4.3.2, 3) reinstall the most recent version of RStudio RStudio 2023.12.1+402

suggested by: L Tyrone

thank you!!

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept your own answer by clicking the tick. This will turn the answer box green and signal to others that the solution worked. Thanks, and happy plotting!